# CEDR EasyJet Complaint worth it?

Tags: uk, europe, cancellations, easyjet, ec261

I recently raised an EU261 cancellation claim against EasyJet for a flight from Bristol to Prague that was cancelled. I was only going to Prague for the weekend and the next available EasyJet flight to Prague was the following the evening so I took the flight refund.

The flight was originally cancelled due to a drunk Stag Group and the inexperience/poor management of the EasyJet staff. However EasyJet claim the prior for its cancellation reasoning.

Long story short the Stag group took around 30mins to remove from the plane at which point they claimed to still have items onboard. The result was it took the EasyJet crew over 3 hours to 'identify' bags, first by collecting passports of passengers who had bags in the hold to try and identify them, when they realised this wouldn't work they unloaded all the bags and got passengers to identify their baggage. By the time all this palaver had gone on we were then informed the crew would be running over their safe operating hours.

My argument was that EasyJet should have a strict procedure for this, not the cabin crew dithering of how best to problem solve. Also considering this was a Friday night flight to Prague you expect them to be wholly prepared for potential passenger disruption. EasyJet simply claim it was the Stag groups fault and it was 'out of their control'.

My EU261 claim has already been rejected, is it worth me pursuing an ADR with CEDR considering the above. I've reasoned that inexperience of the staff wont have been documented as part of the reason for this fight cancellation and are CEDR going to simply look at this as the Stags fault.

Thanks

Comment: Collecting passports of passengers with bags in the hold? That's an interesting one. Offloading everything and getting passengers to identify their bags is a relatively standard procedure, but probably only after the standard and normally more efficient ones fail or in case there are serious security concerns. The normal procedure is that they have the tag numbers of the luggage checked-in by the disembarked passengers and they can find those easily (even if not quickly). Must have failed to find them due to bags being misplaced or something similar...

Comment: It does not matter that EasyJet "rejects" it, they are always trying to pull off that stunt. You can use www.getairhelp.com which have heavily automated the process and send correct letters to the airlines.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion it is worth pursuing, although you might have to go to court to claim your compensation. It is common for airlines to claim anything and everything is beyond their control, but so far the courts seem to be disagreeing with them rather steadily.

Here the cause of the delay was with how the luggage was stored. The way airlines store the luggage in hold is indeed not suitable to quickly find a bag - as known by anyone who been on a plane with missing passengers and had to wait for their luggage to be offloaded. However how they store the luggage inside their airplane is definitely under their control.